# prompt login after redirect to WWW

Tags: apache, .htaccess, authentication, redirect

I need to redirect to WWW first and then ask for basic auth

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

AuthType Basic
AuthName "test"
AuthUserFile /home/www/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

If I go to **test.com** I see the login prompt. I enter the credentials and then I get redirected to **www.test.com** and prompted again for the login. I want to redirect to WWW first so I enter the credentials once.

Comment: Do you have Plesk ?

Comment: nope. just plain apache

Comment: Try this code: `RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`